# How to convert categorical data like Rs. 2,92,667 to integer and float type?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I'm trying to convert Rs. 2,92,667 to integer type but I'm confused like how to remove Rs. and commas from it .

`cars = [int(x.split('Rs. ')[-1]) for x in cars['Ex-Showroom_Price']]`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-b9318b3d5174> in <module>
----> 1 cars = [int(x.split('Rs. ')[-1]) for x in cars['Ex-Showroom_Price']]

<ipython-input-14-b9318b3d5174> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 cars = [int(x.split('Rs. ')[-1]) for x in cars['Ex-Showroom_Price']]

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,92,667'
```

[**This is what I tried**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wZkB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Split the string and remove commas from the numeric part.

```
rs_string = 'Rs. 2,92,667'
rs_integer = int(rs_string.split()[-1].replace(',',''))
print(rs_integer)
```

**Output:**

```
292667
```

**Note:**

This will also work for a string that does not contain the 'Rs.' preamble but does assume that the resulting values can be converted to *int*. Just replace the call to *int* with *float* if required

Comment: @SHWETABHAGAT Your code makes no attempt to remove the commas

Comment: can you please tell me what am I doing wrong in  [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N05T95Tz1HhqIzc4urDNO4amArmGRDYc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @SHWETABHAGAT Links to external sites are not acceptable. Please post the code you're having trouble with in the original question

Comment: @SHWETABHAGAT Do not add images. They are not acceptable

Comment: ok, sorry I didn't knew that